# Problem with Basic SQL Stuff

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Im a beginner in SQL.I am having a problem with it.
First of all I shd let u know I installed SQL 2005 Server n then made a ConsoleApp and rest of code is under :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=userid;" +
                                       "Password=validpassword;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "Data Source=localhost;" +
                                       "connection timeout=300");



            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }


            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (Column1, Column2) " +
                                      "Values ('string', 1)", myConnection);

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();



        }
    }
}
```

WHEN I RUN IT...I get **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll** with  myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Kidnly guide me where Im going wrong.I just want to do simple stuff.Insert something n then read it.But I get error even at inserting.

Comment: Is it openning the connection ok?

Comment: Has the table already been created?

Answer (score 6):

You aren't using a database.  Set the Initial Catalog query in your connection string to the database that the table "table" is in.  Or, do INSERT INTO dbName..table VALUES ...

Also, check out [ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/). Learn it, use it, love it.

Comment: Excellent catch! No "Initial Catalog=" or "database=" in the connection string - where does that "table" exist then? :-)

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be missing the Initial Catalog parameter in your connection.  It should be "Initial Catalog = DatabaseName".  Also if you are using Trusted Connection you don't need the user id and password parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Start my moving your exception handling to contain the ExecuteNonQuery, then edit your question with the full exception.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=userid;" +
                                       "Password=validpassword;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "Data Source=localhost;" +
                                       "connection timeout=300");


            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();

                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (Column1, Column2) " +
                                      "Values ('string', 1)", myConnection);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();    
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps use a Using statement too?

Answer (score 1):

When you installed SQL Server 2005 did you put it into mixed mode? You would need this to pass in a username and password. I am not sure what .NET will do with a username/password and trusted connection = true in the connection string. Are you getting an open connection?

You also need a database name in your connection string.

I can't add a commet on your post so I will add it here. You need to start up the SQL Server Management Studio to get to your database and future tables. Then go to help and begin reading books online about how to create your tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is either an issue with the connection to the database- wrong username, password, and/or server, or the table and columns do not exist. I would place a breakpoint on the catch statement and take a look at the exception to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

If you trap the exception, or debug the console app so that you can see the exception details, you should be able to find out the full details of the error by examining the message of the exception, or the inner exception.

As Chad mentioned, this could be a simple naming problem where the table or columns you specified in the query don't exist in the database you are pointed to.  Alternatively, there could be an issue with the type of data you are trying to interpret.  The DB Server message that comes back on the exception will let you know more.